# Showing validation errors to view

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-validation

I want to show the validation errors to the users in comma seperated

i.e.,

The username field is required, The password field is required

So far i can able to send the validation error messages to the view like this

```
$validation->messages()
```

But the only thing i can't able to do

```
@if(Session::has('Message'))
<p class="alert">{{ Session::get('Message') }}</p>
@endif
```

or

```
{{ $errors->first('username', '<div class="error">:message</div>') }}
```

The only thing i can do is to pass the messages as normal text.

So, How can i pass the validation messages to a view by plain text (rather than array or object)

**Update :**

I mean to say i can do any works only in controller and not in view

Comment: Can you please post complete code in your view and how they are output in your template?

Comment: Do you want me to show how the errors messages are displayed so far ?

Comment: No, I meant the full code you use to get errors set and code to display them to the user.

Comment: Sorry, if i understand your question correctly ... it was already in the question.. its laravel default way to throw and receive the errors..

Answer (score 1):

in controller:

```
return implode(',',$validation->errors()->all());
```